# How to manage JQuery dynamically loaded forms in a panel in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, postback, webforms

I wish to dynamically load various MVC forms, into an arbitrary panel on a page, but maintain the current URL on postback of the changes (i.e. not leave the parent page).

I need each form to act as if it was still on its own page, for convenience of MVC authoring and validation, but not wind up on the child form page after a submit.

A hardwired example (in the actual version the target is data-driven) of a load might be:

```
that.element.children(".tilepanel").click(function () {
    $(this).load('/form/personaldetails .main-content');
});
```

This extracts the `.main-content` section, including headings and form, from views/form/personaldetails.cshtml and inserts it into the panel clicked.

Unfortunately the basic behavior of the form submit will either attempt to postback to the current controller (which does not know about the `PersonalDetails` model), or to `controllers/formscontroller.cs` (to the `PersonalDetails` method) and wind up on the views/form/personaldetails.cshtml page.

I am open to any suggestions (update panels, server-side redirects, JQuery postbacks, switch to SPA model, whatever) but looking for the most elegant solution that does not require a major change to the individual pages and will stop the current page changing.

### Possible solution #1 (Ajax post) - This works:

```
$(this).load('/form/personaldetails .main-content', function () {
    _connectFormSubmit($(this), '/form/personaldetails');
});

_connectFormSubmit: function (panel, url) {
    panel.find('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: panel.find('form').serialize(),
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                panel.html($(data).find('.main-content'));
                _connectFormSubmit(panel, url);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The initial problem I had with this approach was the need to re-connect the submit handler when the whole form was replaced on each post, so it is *kind of recursive*. This one works and will do until somebody comes up with a better approach. If no-one comes up with a better approach I will move this to an answer.

*Apologies for the semi-object declarations, but I had to strip it from a working project*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete solution that will allow you to dynamically insert forms from other MVC 4 pages into a panel and execute any inline Javascript on those pages.

### Simply call with:

```
_loadFormIntoPanel(panel, url, true);
```

Function to get (or post) a form into a panel (e.g. a div):

```
_loadFormIntoPanel: function(panel, url, getit){
    var that = this;
    var re = /<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gm;
    var scripts = "";
    var match;

    // Do an async AJAX get or post
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: getit ? "get" : "post",
        data: getit ? null : panel.find('form').serialize(),
        success: function (data, status, xhr) {
            while (match = re.exec(data)) {
                if (match[1] != "") {
                    scripts += match[0];
                }
            }

            // Replace the entire panel
            panel.html($(data).find('.main-content'));

            // Add the scripts - will evaluate immediately
            panel.append(scripts);

            // Connect the post of the new form back to here
            panel.find('form').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                that._loadFormIntoPanel(panel, url, false);
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

*This represents a full day of research, trial and error, so please credit the source if you use it :)*